# Spread butter flavored with brown butter is too grainy. How to make it silky?

Tags: butter, cream, ghee

A friend of mine tasted a nice butter with brown butter named "Bregott Brynt". I wanted to replicate it and make some at home.

So I started by cooking brown butter that I filtered. I then used 70% swiss alpine butter, 20% brown butter and 10% double cream. I mixed well for a few minutes with a stand mixer.

Then I refrigerated it for a couple of hours and tried it. The taste was there, but the texture was horrible. It is grainy/sandy.

The brown butter by itself was grainy and very dense (due to the water evaporation). I read that crystallization or graininess occurs when the butter melts.

What could I do to make a ghee/brown butter have a soft silky texture?

[image]

The original product is on the top, brown butter is on the left and the final preparation is on the bottom right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, butter (any kind of butter?) crystallize when cooled down to slowly. You must do a tempering similar to chocolate.

1. First eat your butter to a certain temperature for a certain time
2. Quickly cool the butter by putting it in the freezer.
3. When back to 15-20°C mix it well to homogenate it. Salt is not soluble in fat so, during the tempering process, it will float.

You will get soft and silky butter.

From my experience, you can heat it at 80°C for 20 minutes, but the phase transition of butter isn't very clear.